# How to provide an alert option to delete a table data from jstl tag

Tags: javascript, mongodb, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a table which contains data from my mongodb database.

Table data is as:

```
<tr>
        <th class="text-center">Service Code</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Current Price</th>
        <th class="text-center">delete</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="ser" items="${services}" varStatus="status">
<c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/serviceMaster/deleteType?serviceMasterId=${ser.serviceMasterId}" />
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">${ser.serviceCode}</td>
    <td class="text-center">${ser.serviceName} (${ser.serviceAbbreviation})</td>
    <td class="text-center">Service Cost: ${ser.serviceCost}<br>Cost Price: ${ser.costPrice}</td>
<td class="text-center"><a href='<c:out value="${deleteUrl}"/>'><i id="del"
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
                                            style="color: #c12e2a; margin-left: 20px"
                                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

and this URLtriggers my controller which gets the Id and deletes the particular data from my db.

What is the best way to add alert to this approach, or confirmation message before deletion.

Comment: Don't delete data from DB. just maintain a Boolean flag and and change the flag. If you need in this data  in future you can get if you maintain flag.confirmation message before deletion is the best way.

Comment: yes I am doing the same.. I wanted to add alert before performing this delete option.

Answer (score 0):

you can create function on link for confirmation or change as per below code.

```
<a href="www.google.com" onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure?')">Click</a>
```